# Bulk request throws JSON parse exception

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, mime-types, content-type, bulk

I am new to elasticsearch, I am trying to insert data into ES 7.17 using bulk API and I am getting this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('´┐¢' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('´┐¢' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]"},"status":400}
```

My data looks something like that :

```
{"index":{}}
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Nom":"CIMETIERE","Nature":"CIMETIERE","Indice":"C11","Comm_arr":"COMMUNE RURALE","Observatio":"EQUIPEMENT EXISTANT","SURFACE":1770.47710612,"AFFECTATIO":null,"couleur":null,"Shape_Leng":166.456526264,"Shape_Area":1769.1541227},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[291868.8840942383,308735.5601196289,0],[291859.8596801758,308733.67907714844,0],[291856.75329589844,308739.00567626953,0],[291869.6870727539,308735.74908447266,0],[291868.8840942383,308735.5601196289,0]]]]}}
{"index":{}}
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Nom":"CIMETIERE","Nature":"CIMETIERE","Indice":"C10","Comm_arr":"COMMUNE RURALE ","Observatio":"EQUIPEMENT EXISTANT","SURFACE":8452.37668719,"AFFECTATIO":null,"couleur":null,"Shape_Leng":354.093039224,"Shape_Area":8446.0621886},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[289344.2973022461,309379.8327026367,0],[289338.2672729492,309374.85552978516,0],[289366.50830078125,309411.58447265625,0],[289355.5892944336,309389.6077270508,0],[289344.2973022461,309379.8327026367,0]]]]}}
{"index":{}}
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Nom":"CIMETIERE","Nature":"CIMETIERE","Indice":"C09","Comm_arr":"COMMUNE RURALE ","Observatio":"EQUIPEMENT EXISTANT","SURFACE":2994.16626347,"AFFECTATIO":null,"couleur":null,"Shape_Leng":239.91305929,"Shape_Area":2991.9310234},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[292971.89489746094,311026.11767578125,0],[292972.3295288086,311013.4484863281,0],[292957.3724975586,311025.02850341797,0],[292956.70349121094,311031.00091552734,0],[292971.89489746094,311026.11767578125,0]]]]}}
```

And here is my bulk request :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/data/_doc/_bulk -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary "@C:\Users\safaaa\Desktop\data.json"
```

I suppose the problem is because of the special characters in my data.

I was only able to replace the characters "é", "è", "ê" with "e" to test if that is what causes the problem but the error is still there, I am working with a large data so they must be there other special characters like (à, Ø, æ, æ, etc).

I don't wanna fix the data manually, is there any way to ignore those characters in ES ?? Or any ideas about what I should try to fix the problem ??

Comment: can you send a small example of the json file. I'm finding it strange the way you showed the data.

Comment: @andrecoelho.rabbitbr , I updated the question with the data needed

Comment: The problem I had to index was because I had long and float in the coordinates array. I changed the 0 to 0.0 and it worked.
I added text with à, Ø, æ, æ and it worked too. Maybe you have an example where the error occurs.
Anyway you can use a regex to remove the special characters.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?